# Move sharepoint library to another site

Tags: 2010, content-type, lookup-column, sharepoint-fields

I want to move a SharePoint library (2010) to another sitecollection. The problem is that this document library has lookups to other lists, has fields/contenttypes (some were deployed in a solution, others manually created).

How is it recommended to move it to another sitecollection, without losing any data?

1. Powershell?
2. Custom tools?
3. Development?
4. Others?

Comment: It depends on how much is already on the site you want to move it to. Does the lookup lists, fields, and content types exist on the site you want to move the list to?

Comment: Not yet, we need to move this also to the new sitecollection. The sitecollection does not exist at the moment. We can start from scratch.